# Match dataframe observations based on range

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, append

I have two (not necessarily aligned) dataframes like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'B': [3, 4, 3, 10], 'C': [10, 11, 13, 14]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 7, 70, 5, 30], 'B': [3, 30, 20, 110, 1], 'C': [2, 130, 140, 10, 100]})
```

Edit: I want to identify the observations in `df1` in columns `A`, `B` that have an exact match in columns `A` and `B` of `df2`; and a value in column `C` that falls within seven digits of the observations in column `C` of `df2`.

In this example, I want output that looks like this:

```
A       B      C
True    True   False
True    False  False
False   False  False
False   False  True
```

I can figure out how to find an exact match for columns `A` and `B`:

```
    df1.loc[:, ['A', 'B']].isin(df2.loc[:, ['A', 'B'])
```

Comment: In your expected output, wouldn't the last entry of column A be `False`, since 4 != 5? And would the first entry of column C be `False` because abs(10 - 2) > 7?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I've edited this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df1.isin(df2).assign(C=pd.np.abs(df1.C - df2.C).dropna() <= 7)

# Output:
       A      B      C
0   True   True  False
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False   True
```